# How expensive is it to engineer and write the software for an FPGA?

Tags: fpga

I'm willing to pay the costs but I'm trying to get a ballpark estimate. How big of a team would I need? If an EE liked my idea would they be willing to be paid partially in shares of the venture? I'm not trying to go broke doing this.

How do I go about pitching my idea? Are EEs sick of people pitching them ideas?

Comment: It's not for an electronic "Jump to Conclusions" game, I swear.

Comment: How long does it take to write software? *IT DEPENDS ON WHAT YOU ARE DOING*. Also, ideas are cheap, business plans are harder.

Comment: Unless you are Google or Apple, nobody is going to want to be paid in shares. That doesn't put food on the table. Your question is off-topic here, you might get a better reception (or maybe not) at [the EEVBlog forum](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/jobs/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: Pay a consultant to estimate the work/man-power needed and the development timescales. Next go to your bank with a business plan and ask for a loan. The business plan should show the estimated pay-back times due to customer sales.

Comment: If your FPGA software requires special skills like signal processing you might have to pay several times more (per hour) than if it is something very straightforward that anyone familiar with the language could accomplish. You might need two or more people in such cases. For example, I have had algorithms designed and tested in MATLAB and then implemented in FPGA. Few people will highly value shares in an unfunded venture.

Comment: If you hire some undergrads to develop something simple like some glue logic as part of their "work experience" then very little (I wasn't paid at all - unhappy face), if you need someone to design a 4k h265 real-time encoder or a facial recognition system, then expect a big price tag. It's a bit like "how much does it cost to build my thing?" well, what's your thing? How complex is it? An aircraft is much harder to build than an electric piano...

Answer (score 3):

FPGA software is not much different than any other software. You can get a skilled contractor for 70-100€ per hour around here.

Now you only need to know how much time your software will need. This can be between a couple of hours to several years. You'll need to share some more information to get any valid guesstimate.